# Cygwin: Running bash script directly inside dos batch file doesn't work

Tags: windows, batch-file, cygwin

I've searched over the web and still can't figure it out.
I apologise if this sounds like a lazy whinging cry for help -- I really am at wit's end with this one.

I have a bash script located at: 
`/cygdrive/k/Linux Scripts/Scripts/filter.sh`

I've copied the `Cygwin.bat` to `filter.bat`, and changed it as follows:

```
@echo off
L:
chdir L:\Cygwin\bin
bash --login "/cygdrive/k/Linux Scripts/Scripts/filter.sh amc.txt bmo.txt"
```

When I run `filter.bat` by double-clicking on it in Windows Explorer, the console flashes open momentarily and then closes. The script is OK, because it runs from the command line in the Cygwin console.

Is there a way to debug this problem?

Comment: Two thoughts: the terminal may be closing because it executed to completion just fine. Isn't there a command like `pause` that you can add at the end to wait for a key press? Second, the space in the filename may be causing problems; try adding single-quotes around the `/cygdrive/k/Linux Scripts/Scripts/filter.sh` filename.

Comment: @Sarnold. The script normally takes about 30 seconds to complete, and generates another file. In this case, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

Try running the batch file from an already-existing Command Prompt window so you can see any error messages bash might send. I'm guessing it has a problem with "/cygdrive/k/Linux Scripts/Scripts/filter.sh amc.txt bmo.txt" -- as far as it's concerned, that's one argument rather than three. Therefore I would change it to

```
bash --login "/cygdrive/k/Linux Scripts/Scripts/filter.sh" amc.txt bmo.txt
```

Comment: I tried that. Still no difference. Also tried the the -i option as in "bash --login -i ..."

Comment: echristopherson & Sarnold. Just realised that I had a mistake in my script. I had escaped the space in the path name with a backslash. When I remoed this, and used either single or double quotes as you both suggested, then it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent! Please take this opportunity to learn the importance of copy and pasting what you _actually_ tried, rather than re-typing content. Thanks!